# Is a draggable and resizable textbox/textarea possible using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I can get the drag to work, but the resizing is not cooperating.  (The behavior is evident using either the text box or the text area.)  I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7.2.

Here's my attempt:

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
    <TITLE>Drag/Resize TextBox Workbench</TITLE> 
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="js/ui/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#ta1" ).resizable( { cancel: '' } );
    $( "#ta1" ).draggable( { cancel: '' } );
});
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <form>
            <input type='text' class='property' id='tb1' />
            <textarea id='ta1' class='property'>Hello</textarea>
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Default behavior in chrome :)

Comment: [jQuery Textarea Resize](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer) plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the `<textarea>` in a `<div>` or another block-level tag and making that draggable instead?

Comment: That still wouldn't help in making it resizable, though.

Comment: I wrapped both elements in individual spans and they both seem to behave now.  I can resize and drag.