# Draggable and resizable textarea using Jquery- cannot enter text using left click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a textarea draggable and resizable using Jquery. I referred to similar question asked here on Stackoverflow at [Is a draggable and resizable textbox/textarea possible using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717589/is-a-draggable-and-resizable-textbox-textarea-possible-using-jquery).

HTML for textarea

> ```
>     <div id="text1" style="margin-left:100px; width:190px; height:50px; ">
>     <form>
>     <textarea id='ta1' style="width:180px; height:15px" class='property'>Right click to enter      text</textarea>
> </form>
> </div>
> ```

I am able to make the textarea draggable by closing it in a div and making the div draggable and I make the text area resizable as follows:

> ```
>    $( "#ta1" ).resizable( { cancel: '' } );
>      $( "#text1" ).draggable( { cancel: '' } );
>      $('#ta1').focus(function() {
>      $(this).text('');
>      });
> ```

**The only issue is that I cannot enter text into the textarea by normal left click.** The only way to enter text in the textarea is right click (I disabled context menu on right click). Can anyone explain why this is the case? How can I enable entering of text using normal left click?

My code is here at - http://jsbin.com/iboxoy/61/edit#javascript,html

Thanks,
Shan

Comment: uhh... why would you write `$(document)[0]`... you realize that is just calling `document`.. So Write document!! you need to understand what $() is doing each time you call it before you start using jQuery. or else you will end up spending more time trying to fix crazy ass issues like this than you would have if you had just learned proper js.

Comment: 1. Its besides the point 2. $(document)[0] is to disable context menu (its from here - http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/disabling-right-mouse-click-menu-with-jquery/) on right click because earlier left click was highjacked (as mentioned below). $(document) by itself did not disable the context menu. 3. I don't need to use it now because left click works on the textbox. Thanks.

Comment: 1. it's not besides the point, it's doing it right. 2. I didn't say use $(document), I said use document. as in document.oncontextmenu. selecting [0] from the jQuery object is just [selecting the native DOM element](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_pull_a_native_DOM_element_from_a_jQuery_object.3F) or in this case `document`

Comment: one last kick before I let this horse die (and your overall performance with it), that code is literally doing; 1) take the document object and wrap it with the bloated jquery library of properties and functions. 2) pull the native DOM element out from the bloat, which is document. 3) attach the oncontextmenu handler.... so once again, my point was why did you have to use jquery there? it was not needed. and yes it does affect the overall performance of the page. http://jsperf.com/jquery-bloated-mess *i know it's not much of a difference.. but for the exact same code..*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left click is being highjacked by the draggable plugin.  If you define a handle to drag you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks natedavisolds. The solution works.  I just changed the drag jquery code to : $( "#text1" ).draggable( { cancel: '#ta1' } );. This way the handle is only surrounding div but not the actual textbox. The left click is not highjacked in this case.